# How to get power button keycode without screen lock

Tags: android

I 'm trying to display `keycode` when user press specific key in my program. I can get all of keys keycode, i.e. vol_up / vol_down / Camera etc. But the screen will be locked/off when I press Power button, and I can't see the keycode of power key in the screen. Could someone tell me how to get the keycode of Power button and the screen won't be off/locked when pressing it?

Thanks a lot.
Qin

Answer (score 0):

You can't. See this answer by Mark Murphy, from Google: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/pNtN7xvaqNk